# Is a manual save required for when overrideing resolveConflicts in NSMergePolicy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, merge-conflict-resolution

I am subclassing NSMergePolicy in order to use my own custom logic for merge conflict resolution. I am wondering what happens after I make my changes to the `sourceObject`? Do I need to call save on it's managedObjectContext? Will it save automatically? Also, what happens if I do nothing to the object and don't call save? Will the object just not get saved?

Answer (score 0):

A manual save should not be required as long as `resolveConflicts:error:` returns YES, but make *sure* your implementation calls the super implementation. Much of the magic happens in there.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example of an implementation of this, by chance?  My merge policy subclass's `resolveConflicts:error:` method isn't being called.